# PDF extension does not load

Tags: php

I'm using [filethingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/documentation) to upload files to my website.
When i upload files it gaves following error.

```
[07-Feb-2013 08:52:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 08:55:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 08:55:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 08:57:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 08:57:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 08:58:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 08:58:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 08:58:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 08:58:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 08:58:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 08:58:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 09:02:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 09:02:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 09:02:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 09:02:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[07-Feb-2013 09:02:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Unknown modifier '\' in /home/softlogi/public_html/Softlogic_Research/ft-admin.php on line 113
[07-Feb-2013 09:03:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

And displays

> name.pdf was not uploaded. File type not allowed

Why is this issue occoers and how can i fix it?

Comment: The obvious question; do you have `pdf` extension installed?

Comment: I'm new to PHP... i think i haven't... can you explain how can i install it ?

Comment: In general with this sort of question, PHP version and OS/version is very helpful. Would you edit that into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've added 'pdf.so' to your php.ini, without actually [installing the extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
```

Looks like pdf extension is not installed correctly. You can read the install [section](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/documentation#install) of the plugin to fix this error. Then read about how to [use](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/documentation#plugins) the plugin. Just follow the instruction and you will be fine.